# sort second column based on sorted first column in javascript or jquery keeping first sort as it is

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input :

```
col1 | col2
24     89
21     43
5      23
5      1
78     67
```

Output :

```
col1 | col2
5      1
5      23
21     43
24     89
78     67
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: this is exactly how to not ask a good question... this input and output just gives context, but we don't know the structure of the data... furthermore, you should show what you have tried so far, because we are not here to do your job

Comment: There are a lot search results about this scenario. Don't understand why you don't first research.